# How to center dialog on parent even if parent was moved

Tags: java, swing, awt, intellij-14

I have an application with buttons.  When a button is clicked, a jdialog is launched.  If the application window is moved on the screen, the jdialog is not centered on the application.  I'm using the following code in my jdialog:

```
pack();
setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
setModal(true);
setVisible(true);
```

How do I center the dialog on the parent even if the parent is moved?

Comment: Please don't keep rolling back edits. They were made in good faith to improve your question.

Comment: You don't.  Once the dialog is created, it's a separate window from the application window.

Comment: The edits made were useless and the question added was a repeat of the question itself.